# Blank screen, CentOS 6.5

Tags: linux, centos-6, dell-poweredge

I'm on a Dell PowerEdge 2850, and I recently installed CentOS 6.5, and it worked well for a while, then recently whenever I booted into the OS like after the BIOS screen, everything went blank and it stopped outputting through my graphics card. I was still able to access it through VNC, but nothing would output through either VGA port on the PowerEdge.

The same thing happens when I try to boot of the Live CD too, or when I try to install it off of there. The only way I can get it to output something is by booting and using text-only mode, other than that, there's no output whatsoever with CentOS.

Comment: You should check out the X logs.

Comment: How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 0):

I saw you ask how to check the X logs.  I'm brand new to Linux so I hope I'm helping you out here:

This will show you all the various log options you have:

```
ls -l /var/logs
```

What I believe @Cristian was asking you to check out is this:

```
cat /var/logs/Xorg.0.log
```

You can also weed through your messages maybe?

```
cat /var/logs/messages
```

You can also view errors by using this command:

```
grep -i error /var/log/messages
```

Not really sure if that will show you any error reports or not.  Sorry, I know this doesn't answer your question.